# OBJ Line Reader

Tags: object, vector, lua, 3d, vertex

I want to read an OBJ file in Lua. I am new to the file writing/reading system in Lua and wouldn't know how I would do that.
What I want to do:
I want to read each line and see if the line starts with a "v"
if it does I take the numbers after that and store them in a Vector3.
Then I wanna find the lines with "f", and I wanna take the numbers that "f" gives and store that Vector3 in a Polygon object.
Example:

```
v 4.0 7.0 5.0
v 1.0 5.0 1.0
v 5.0 4.0 2.0
v 6.0 1.0 7.0
f 1 4
f 3 2
```

So Vector 1 would be (4,7,5). 2 (1,5,1). 3 (5,4,2). 4 (6,1,7)
Mesh number one would be made up of Vector 1 and 4
Mesh number two would be made up of Vector 3 and 2
This was meant as a short example.
As some might know the f actually look something like this:
`f 1/1/1 2/4/1 4/9/1 3/7/1`
So if there is a way to separate them by the / too, that would be great.

I want to be able to read and store the data of an OBJ file in lua.

Comment: See https://github.com/appgurueu/modlib/blob/master/minetest/obj.lua for a very simple OBJ reader. What have you tried? Essentially parsing an OBJ in Lua boils down to `io.lines` + pattern matching (and other string ops).

Comment: For nice 3D i suggest to have a look at: https://github.com/3dreamengine/3DreamEngine that can handle *.obj files too - It is for: LÖVE [love2d]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store it in `obj`

```lua
obj = io.open('path/to/file'):read('*a')
```

After that you can work with it.
Following is only an example how powerfull `gsub()` could be...

```
> obj:gsub('(%l) (%d+%.%d+) (%d+%.%d+) (%d+%.%d+)', function(a, b, c, d) return(('<%s> [%.1f] [%.1f] [%.1f]'):format(a, b, c, d)) end)
<v> [4.0] [7.0] [5.0]
<v> [1.0] [5.0] [1.0]
<v> [5.0] [4.0] [2.0]
<v> [6.0] [1.0] [7.0]
f 1 4
f 3 2   4
> obj:gsub('(%l) (%d+) (%d+)', function(a, b, c) return(('<%s> [%s] [%s]'):format(a, b, c)) end)
v 4.0 7.0 5.0
v 1.0 5.0 1.0
v 5.0 4.0 2.0
v 6.0 1.0 7.0
<f> [1] [4]
<f> [3] [2]     2
```

...done in Lua Standalone.
In the Function of `gsub()` you can do something with the Match on Pattern.

Comment: Thank you. This is a great answer. How would I access the return values though?

Comment: In the gsub() function before the return you can use a, b, c or and d to access/store them in a global variable (table)